# fitting a non-smooth curve that is described by three equations

Tags: matlab, parameters, transition, curve-fitting, toolbox

I'm facing the following problem:

I would like to fit a curve which is described by an underlying model containing a set of three different functions for three different x-ranges in order to determine three unknown parameters (`xG1`, `xG2` and `b`) of four overall within these functions.

For `x` smaller the transition value `xG1` the function-value shall be zero:

```
f(x) = 0 for x < xG1
```

For `x` between `xG1` and `xG2` the curve follows a power-law:

```
f(x) = ( (xG2 - 2 a ⁄ b) / (a - 2 a ⁄ b) )∙[(x - xG1) / (xG2 - xG1)]^2 for xG1 ≤ x ≤ xG2
```

For `x` bigger `xG2` the curve follows a linear relation again:

```
f(x) = (x - 2 a ⁄ b) / (a - 2 a⁄b) for x ≥ xG2
```

So my issue at the moment is that the transition values `xG1` and `xG2` themselves are unknown parameters to be determined, so I can't use a piecewise fitting in order to determine them.

I'm bound to solving this issue using matlab.

I've tried using the curve-fitting-toolbox but it's not really suited for a problem like that, which is why I'm currently trying to find a way using the global optimization-toolbox.

Maybe someone has an idea for solving this issue with the global optimization toolbox or in general with a completely different approach using matlab.

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: One way to tackle this is given in [this](https://de.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf) reference. Fitting the transition of a piecewise function usually fails due to the fact that there is no gradient when implementing it via a step function. This can be solved by a second approach where the step function is chosen soft and sharpened iteratively.

Comment: And thanks for editing the equations - it's much clearer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve a similar problem once where I had a piecewise defined model and the crossover point between the two expressions was a free parameter.

What I did was start with an initial guess of all of the model parameters and then minimized the squared error.  This was done by gradient decent in my case where I numerically evaluated the gradient against all of the model parameters including the crossover point.  I didn't use MATLAB at the time, but the same approach could be applied here.

Another approach is to let MATLAB do all of the heavy lifting.  If you have access to the optimization toolbox you can use functions such as [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) to solve your fit.  `fmincon` takes as an input a vector of the model parameters and a cost function which it attempts to minimize.  The vector of model parameters in this case would also contain the crossover points and your cost function would be the error in the model where the cost function would account for the varying crossovers.

Comment: Thank you so much - I will have a deeper look into this.

Comment: Maybe you can specify this a little bit? Tysm and best regards :))

Comment: And sorry for all these spelling mistakes :D